# ServiceFabric standalone: Failed to get private key file

Tags: ssl, acl, azure-service-fabric

I have a standalone ServiceFabric cluster (3 nodes). I created SSL certificate for server and client authorization. Then I assign certificate thumbprint to a cluster config. Everything work okey( cluster health is Ok and my applications works as well. But there are a lot of errors in Microsoft-ServiceFabric/Admin log. Following warning and errors are writing to log every minute:

- CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey failed. Error:0x80090014
- Can't get    private key filename for certificate. Error: 0x80090014
- All tries to    get private key filename failed.
- Failed to get the Certificate's    private key. Thumbprint: {Cert
  Thumbprint}. Error: E_FAIL
- Failed to    get private key file. x509FindValue: {Cert Thumbprint}, 
  x509StoreName: My, findType: FindByThumbprint, Error E_FAIL
- SetCertificateAcls failed. ErrorCode: E_FAIL Can't ACL
- FabricNode/ServerAuthX509FindValue, ErrorCode E_FAIL

I assinged write permitions to private keys storage for NETWORK SERVICE and SYSTEM. As well I assigned gMSA account for PK storage. But errors still apears in log.
From the other hand everything looks fine, cluster up and running...
Here is my cluster config (security part):

"security":{
     "ServerCredentialType":"X509",
     "ClusterCredentialType":"Windows",
     "WindowsIdentities":{
        "ClustergMSAIdentity":"gMSAccountName@domain.com",
        "ClusterSPN":"http/servicefabric"
     },
     "CertificateInformation":{
        "ServerCertificate": {
               "Thumbprint": "{Cert Thumbprint}",
               "X509StoreName": "My"
           },
        "ClientCertificateThumbprints":[
           {
              "CertificateThumbprint":"{Cert Thumbprint}",
              "IsAdmin":true
           }
        ],
        "X509StoreName": "My"
     }
  },

For x509 certificated creation I used OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017. I follow the steps from this article: https://gist.github.com/harishanchu/e82d759c0235379d1778f799992b5774
Could anyone clarify this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a private key file in the `MachineKeys` folder.
To verify if you have a physical file in the folder run this powershell command:

```
$certThumb = "1D6523F622E33DF46382D081BCA9AE9A2D8D78CC"

Try
{
     $WorkingCert = Get-ChildItem CERT:\LocalMachine\My |where {$_.Thumbprint -match $certThumb} | sort $_.NotAfter -Descending | select -first 1 -erroraction STOP
     $TPrint = $WorkingCert.Thumbprint
     $rsaFile = $WorkingCert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
}
Catch
{
     "Error: unable to locate certificate for $($CertCN)"
     Exit
}

if ($WorkingCert.PrivateKey) {
     $WorkingCert.PrivateKey
}
else
{
     "No private key found"  
}
```

If you get `No private key found` message it means there is no private key in the `MachineKeys` folder. Even though certificate properties can claim otherwise (there is a key icon and message `You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate`). Although I don't know why but for some certificates above situation happens.

As a workaround, follow these steps:

1. Go to the local machine cert store and delete your certificate.
2. Import your certificate to the **local user store first**.
3. Then import your certificate to the local machine store.
4. Set access rights for `Network Service` user.

If you follow steps above, private key will be added to `MachineKeys` folder and error will disappear.
Obviously you have to repeat these steps for every cluster node.