# Service Fabric not starting service Error: FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to publish a Service Fabric service to my local cluster, but it never goes out of this state:

> There was an error during activation.Failed to configure certificate
>   permissions. Error: FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND

[image: Error: FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND]

- Do you know what is this error related to?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details? What service do you have? Where do you run it (cloud vs on-premises) etc.

Comment: Please post your ApplicationManifest.xml

Comment: Have you tried to ensure that the Service Fabric SDKs are up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, SF is unable to find the required cert in Cert store. You can find the missing cert info from the event error logs in Event Viewer-

> %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-ServiceFabric%4Admin.evtx

Check using Certificate Manager if this cert is present and not expired. You can use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137808/623487) also.

More info regarding the required certs can be found in this file. -

> C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\{**AppNameFromSf**}\App.1.0.xml